# No module named XXX on another PC

Tags: python

I created a program using some third-party libraries (PIL in particular). Now I want to send this program to my friend, who has a python interpreter but doesn't have PIL lib installed. What files should I put in the archive (and where can I find them?), so that this friend will be able to run my program without thinking about installing any third-party libs?

Comment: Is there any reason that your friend doesnt want to use pip ?

Comment: @CreamyOreo, in my case I just don't want to bother them, but the main reason for this question is the 'technology' of making independent programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to make an independent program out of python, I would recommend **pyinstaller** this is a good wrapper that wraps your python code as an exe file so that you are able to send it to ur friends without him/her installing any dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You should probably think about wrapping your program in a python package which contains information about all dependencies. When the package is distributed (send to your friend), the user can simple install the package with all dependencies using pip.